# Flask cannot find templates and static folder under app folder instead it always looks at root folder

Tags: python, flask, web-deployment

I have running into this error but can't find the solution.

Directory structure looks like this.

```
Project
|   .env
|   .gitignore
|   Pipfile
|   Pipfile.lock
|   run.py
|       
---app
    |   controllers.py
    |   models.py
    |   __init__.py
    |   
    ---static
    |       main.css
    |       
    ---templates
    |       about.html
    |       home.html
    |       layout.html
```

run.py  has the following code.

```
from app import app
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, port=6060)
```

**init**.py looks like this
from flask import Flask

```
app = Flask('__name__', template_folder='app\\templates')
app.config['EXPLAIN_TEMPLATE_LOADING'] = True

from app import models
from app import controllers
```

First I was running into an issue because it could not find the `templates` folder, so I turned on template loading and noticed that it was not loading the path correctly. `templates` folder is inside the `app/` folder, but the debugging log was showing that the scrip is looking for `tempaltes` folder in the root. So, I hard coded in the app initialization. I still don't know why, but it's working.

The problem now, however is that script is not able to find `app/static/main.css` file as well.

in the `layout.html` page I have the following line.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" . href="{{url_for('static', filename='main.css')}}">
```

When I look at the source code of the page, it shows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" . href="/static/main.css">
```

Again, it's lookin in the root folder, instead of `app` folder.

Instead of tweaking and finding hacks, I want to fix it so it always looks under `app` not root. I think it will also fix the `templates` issue.

Please advise.

Comment: in my case I had to provide full Path of the template folder (not relative): Path(Path(__file__).parent,"whatever_folders","templates")

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I think this line is your issue

```
app = Flask('__name__', template_folder='app\\templates')
```

That templates folder should be default, and I don't quote out the __name__... try changing that to

```
app = Flask(__name__)
```

and then just try the jinja you have there

```
{{url_for('static', filename='main.css')}}
```

which should also be default. I'm really not at all sure why it's not working, but that might be the issue.